# How to send a mailing that includes multiple emails for individual contacts

Tags: civimail

Is there a setting allowing to send a mailing to all of a contact's emails?  For example, being able to send a mailing that will reach both Home and Work emails.  All I can see is the "Enable multiple bulk email address for a contact" setting under CiviMail Component Settings which doesn't seem to do this.  From what I gather, it automatically adjusts the Primary email when a contacts email bounces, but doesn't actually email all of their listed emails.

Comment: The setting you mention will only cause all email addresses that are checked for bulk email to be sent, so you are correct in your assessment.

Comment: Do we need to change the labeling/help text and documentation for this setting to make it more clear?

Comment: I'm realizing that we never marked anything with the check box for bulk mail next to the email address, we added people to the Group that was associated with their list.

Comment: @NoahMiller the wording I see in the documentation is "One of these email addresses can be explicitly marked as the address which receives all bulk mailings such as e-newsletters and announcements".  Yet for each email there is a check box to designate for Bulk Mailings and multiple can be selected at the same time.  What's confusing is that there is also the radio button for Primary email, which is what I thought was going on when only one email was receiving our newsletter.  Some users have more than one address they want to get the newsletter to and I don't see an option for that.